# ggplot2, labels from column 1 but values from column 2 implemented automatically rather than by hand?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

The problem seemed simple enough. I have three columns of data in a dataframe. Row one is a score, row two is the rank, and row three is the corresponding name. I want to create a graph in ggplot2 that orders the scores by rank.

The issue is that I do not want the x label to be the rank but instead the individuals name. The other problem is that I cannot do this by hand (which would be easy enough).

An example of the data set would look like

```
    var1 <- c("jon", "jamie", "jessie", "jennifer", "jordan") 
    var2 <- c(91, 92, 85, 99, 88)
    var3 <- c(3,2,5,1,4)
    data <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
```

I have been currently trying to use labels but that has not worked out too well. The core issue is how ggplot2 orders things.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = var3, y = var2)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
scale_x_discrete(name ="Name", labels = (data$var3 = data$var1))
```

Currently the labels are the rank. What I would like them to be are the names.

The name order should be jennifer, jamie, jon, jordan, and jessie. Instead, I just get the name order of the row, i.e. jon, jamie, jessie, jennifer, jordan.

Comment: Don't use `as.data.frame(cbind(var1, var2, var3))`. `cbind` converts everything to matrix, which means all your numbers become strings. Use the simpler code `data.frame(var1, var2, var3)` instead.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perhaps inelegant - using both `order()` and `reorder()` feels clunky to me - but it gets the job done with limited changes to your original script.

#### Setup:

```
library(tidyverse)

var1 <- c('jon', 'jamie', 'jessie', 'jennifer', 'jordan') 
var2 <- c(91, 92, 85, 99, 88)
data <- data.frame(var1, var2)
```

#### Reorder the levels of `var1`:

```
levels(data[,'var1'])
data[,'var1'] <- reorder(data[,'var1'], -data[,'var2'])
levels(data[,'var1'])
```

#### Giving:

```
> levels(data[,'var1'])
[1] "jamie"    "jennifer" "jessie"   "jon"      "jordan"  
> data[,'var1'] <- reorder(data[,'var1'], -data[,'var2'])
> levels(data[,'var1'])
[1] "jennifer" "jamie"    "jon"      "jordan"   "jessie"
```

#### From which we can plot as desired:

```
ggplot(data) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = var1, y = var2), stat = 'identity') + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = 'Name', labels = levels(data[,'var1']))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, using this code, no labels are in the ggplot2 output.

Comment: Using your original example it does- working on solving the update now

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this                                                                                      var1 <- c("jon", "jamie", "jessie", "jennifer", "jordan") 
        var2 <- c(91, 92, 85, 99, 88)
        var3 <- c(3,2,5,1,4)
        data <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
ggplot(data, aes(x = var3, y = var2)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
scale_x_discrete(name ="Name", labels = var1[order(-var2)])

Comment: What I get is no x axis tick labels.

Comment: Theres probably a more elegant way but I'm doing this in the phone and feeding the kids

Answer (score 1):

For me it always works better this way:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  arrange(ranks) %>%
  mutate(names = factor(ranks, , names, T), ranks = NULL) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = names, y = marks)) +
  geom_col(fill = 'salmon', alpha = .5) + 
  ggthemes::theme_tufte()
```

[image: salmon]

```
dat <- data.frame(
  names  = c("jon", "jamie", "jessie", "jennifer", "jordan"),
  marks  = c(91, 92, 85, 99, 88),
  ranks  = c(3, 2, 5, 1, 4)
)
```